# How can we consider only unbiased estimator of zero 'based on sufficient statistic'?

Tags: sufficient-statistics

According to this answer :   https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/37710/138097

I understand the logic, except following sentense: 
[ note: because of sufficiency, we have reduced the problem of showing uncorrelatedness with every estimator of 0 to only have to show it for **estimators that depend only on T** ]

What about the other statistics that is unbiased estimator of zero but not depend on T?

Is there something that i missed about "because of sufficiency" ?